# how to write Test Code to get more coverage rate?

Tags: apex

i'm a junior salesforce developer according to user reqest "Duplicat ContentNote.TextPreview to custom object when user create a note on the opportunity" .
 but i found i cannot create any trigger on the ContentNote so I create on the ContentVersion .
 Now the trigger is working but when i write the test case to test this trigger the coverage only 28%. i don't konw how to modify my test case to get 75% coverage ,pleae help me .
 thanks

**Trigger :**

```
trigger tgrGetContentNotes on ContentVersion (after insert) {

    List<ContentVersion> cvList =  [SELECT Id,ContentDocumentId,TextPreview,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate From ContentVersion  WHERE id =:Trigger.new 
                                    AND IsLatest = TRUE AND IsMajorVersion = true LIMIT 1];   
    IF (cvList.size() > 0 ) {
        String l_cdId = cvList.get(0).ContentDocumentId;
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdList = [SELECT LinkedEntityId,ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink
                                            WHERE ContentDocumentId = :l_cdId ];
         IF (cdList.size()>0) {

                FOR (Integer i=0; i<cdlist.size();i++){
                IF (cdList.get(i).ShareType =='V') {
                    //System.debug(i+'LinkedEntityId :'+cdList.get(i).LinkedEntityId);


                List<Opportunity> oppList  = [SELECT ID,NAME FROM Opportunity WHERE ID = :cdList.get(0).LinkedEntityId LIMIT 1];
                IF (oppList.size() > 0){
                String l_textpreview;
                System.debug('oppid :'+oppList.get(0).Id); 
                IF (cvList.get(0).TextPreview.length() >255) {
                 l_textpreview =  cvList.get(0).TextPreview.substring(0,254);                  
                 }
               ELSE{
                   l_textpreview =  cvList.get(0).TextPreview;
               }            



                     List<OpportunityNotes__c> oppNotesList = [SELECT CVId__c,ContentDocumentId__c FROM OpportunityNotes__c 
                                                              WHERE ContentDocumentId__c =:cvList.get(0).ContentDocumentId];

                      IF (oppNotesList.size()  > 0 ){
                          OpportunityNotes__c opportunityNotesObj = [SELECT TextPreview__c FROM OpportunityNotes__c 
                                                                    WHERE  ContentDocumentId__c =:cvList.get(0).ContentDocumentId];

                          opportunityNotesObj.TextPreview__c = l_textpreview;
                          Update opportunityNotesObj;
                      } 
                      ELSE {
                          OpportunityNotes__c opportunityNotesObj  = new OpportunityNotes__c();

                          opportunityNotesObj.OpportunityId__c = oppList.get(0).Id;
                          opportunityNotesObj.OpportunityName__c=oppList.get(0).Name;
                          opportunityNotesObj.CVId__c = cvList.get(0).Id;
                          opportunityNotesObj.ContentDocumentId__c= cvList.get(0).ContentDocumentId;
                          opportunityNotesObj.TextPreview__c = l_textpreview;
                          insert opportunityNotesObj;
                        }
              // }          

                } // cdList.get(i).ShareType =='V'

              }             

            }//FOR

      }// cdList.size()>0    

     } // cvList.size() > 0
```

**Test Code**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class testInsertOppNote {
     public static @isTest void testInsertOppNote(){

          Test.startTest();
          Account accobj = new Account(
          name='AccountTest',
          Type='Partner',
          Partner_Type__c='Solution Partner',
          Partner_Segment__c = 'Design Partner',
          currencyIsoCode = 'USD',
          recordtypeid='01261000000ieY1AAI', // AOA Account Record Type
          BillingCountry='Netherlands',
          BillingCity ='BEST',
          BillingPostalCode='2100',
          BillingStreet='TEST',
          ShippingCountry='Netherlands',
          ShippingCity ='BEST',
          ShippingPostalCode='2100'
          );
          insert accobj;

          Contact conobj = new Contact(AccountId=accobj.id,
          FirstName='Vicky',
          LastName='Hsin',
          Email='vickyhsin@aopen.com');

          insert conobj;   
          Opportunity oppobj = new Opportunity(Name='VH TEST', 
                                              RecordTypeId='01261000000ibKBAAY', // AOA Solution 
                                              Accountid = accobj.id,
                                              StageName='Prospecting' ,
                                              CloseDate = DATE.today(),
                                              CurrencyIsoCode='EUR',
                                              description='VH TEST'); // mark g 

          insert oppobj;







         ContentVersion newContent =new ContentVersion(); 
          newContent.ContentURL='http://www.google.com/'; 
          newContent.Title ='Google.com'; 

          insert newContent;

          ContentVersion testContent = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion where Id = :newContent.Id]; 
          Id l_id = testContent.ContentDocumentId;

           List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

          ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
          contentlink.LinkedEntityId=oppobj.id;
          contentlink.contentdocumentid = l_id;
          //contentlink.contentdocumentid = [select contentdocumentid from contentversion where id =:testContent.contentdocumentid].Id;
          contentlink.ShareType = 'V';

          insert contentlink;


          OpportunityNotes__c opportunityNotes = new OpportunityNotes__c (OpportunityId__c=oppobj.id, OpportunityName__c= oppobj.name, ContentDocumentId__c = testContent.contentdocumentid);



         insert opportunityNotes ;


         Test.stopTest();



     }

}
```

Comment: The best way to write tests is to look at the requirements that drove the coding you did and create test methods that check that each requirement is being met. Then code coverage is just a way to confirm you didn’t miss anything. Also see e.g. [Testing and Code Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm). You can find out exactly which lines are not covered via the developer Console and then add more tests that setup the data so that the various if/else branches are taken.

Answer (score 0):

Just create appropriate user and use run as context. So that contentlink.ShareType = 'V' will match otherwise it will be "I".

Check the debug log.